# calling batch command from c++ code

Tags: c++

I want to call a batch command (not file) from my C++ code. To be more precise, I want to call command `start`. When I tried command from `cmd` it is working fine, but it is not working from C++ code.

I am using `CreateProcess` API to call `start` command, for example: `start firefox`

Comment: `CreateProcess()` does not know about "internal" CMD commands. You need to invoke the command with `cmd.exe /c`, e.g.: `cmd.exe /c start firefox`.

Comment: @Christian.K thanks man! It worked.

Comment: Looks like a VeryBadIdeaToBeginWith®